# Programmatically obtaining USB file system format

Tags: linux, usb, embedded-linux, mount

I need to mount a USB drive to an embedded system, running Linux. The USB could be in FAT, NTFS or ExFAT format.

How can i handle this in code so that I pass proper type in mount command such as

mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /mnt

So I have tried mount with:

mount -t vfat,ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt

This command gives invalid argument, but it successfully mounts the USB if USB is in NTFS or VFAT format. However if i try to give

mount -t vfat,ntfs,exfat /dev/sda1 /mnt

The command fails.

Any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: Is exfat supported by both your kernel and mount program? Does it work if you specify `-t exfat` alone?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I think I need to install exfat utils in the system.

Answer (score 1):

From the mount manual page:

> If  no  -t  option  is  given, or if the auto type is specified,
>   mount will try to guess the desired type.  Mount uses the  blkid
>   library  for guessing the filesystem type...

Is libblkid available for your embedded system?

Try:

```
mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

or

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

And as mentioned in the comments, make sure the kernel on your embedded system supports exfat.

Comment: I tried with auto as well. But it doesn't work.
blkid exists but it doesn't give the file system type in command output.

blkid /dev/block/*
/dev/block/sda1: UUID="AE12479512476207"